# Disable bundle product if disable any product in bundle

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I want to disable bundle products if having disabled any simple product separated in the bundle.
let me know any way to do automated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like get product collection and use gettypeinstance()

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == ProductType::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            $children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), true);
            $shouldDisable = false;

            foreach ($children as $childIds) {
                foreach ($childIds as $childId) {
                    $childProduct = $product->getById($childId);
                    if (!$childProduct || $childProduct->getStatus() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED) {
                        $shouldDisable = true;
                        break 2; // Exit both loops
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($shouldDisable) {
                $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
                $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'status');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code for disable Bundle product if any child is disable from parent bundle product**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="disbale_bundle_product" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\DisbaleBundleProduct" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Observer**

**DisbaleBundleProduct.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class DisbaleBundleProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $bundleSelection;
    protected $_productloader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type $bundleSelection
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        if ($product->getStatus() == 2) {
            $budelIds = $this->bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($product->getEntityId());
            if (count($budelIds)) {
                foreach ($budelIds as $budelKey => $budelVal) {
                    $productData = $this->_productloader->create()->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())->load($budelVal);
                    $productData->setStatus(2);
                    $productData->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```